# How to turn off the time logging in Rails migrations with POstgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Everytime I run the migrations, I get a printout like this

```
Time: 0.393 ms
Time: 0.222 ms
Time: 0.174 ms
Time: 0.136 ms
Time: 0.138 ms
Time: 0.205 ms
Time: 0.468 ms
```

I'd like to disable this, but I can't seem to succeed. I already tried changing the `postgresql.conf` to disable client logging, etc. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

```
set  log_min_duration_statement =-1;
```

this can be set per session, per user, or per database, the above sets it for your session only.

```
alter user fred set log_min_duration_statement =-1;
alter database wordpress set log_min_duration_statement =-1;
```

setiting it to `-1` disables it, setting it to `0` causes all queries to be logged.